# Tricky issue when I attempted to use JNA to bring a non-foreground window to foreground

Tags: java, winapi, jna

This has been confusing me for several weeks, but still I have no clue.
I tend to use JNA to implement automation on certain web page (only compatible with IE browser).

As the first step, I want raise a browser with specified url (say www.google.com)
and then 
1) find window by name 
2) use certain api to bring it the top

Here is the code

```
    HWND window = user32.FindWindow(null, "${WINDOW NAME}");
    user32.ShowWindow(window, 1);
    User32.INSTANCE.SetForegroundWindow(window);
    User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
    User32.INSTANCE.MoveWindow(window, 7, 7, 777, 777, true);
```

The above code is invoked in a button's click event listener. 
However, after the browser initialized, nothing happened with the 1st click.
But window does appear and resize with 2nd click.

I've ever tried BringWindowToTop / SetWindowPos, neither works.

Anyway, I'm not familiar with Win Api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UI automation is done using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). No need to force a random process' window(s) to the foreground.

Comment: I would use Java to implement it though it might be hard.

Comment: It might, well, actually work.....